# Python: Creating a new instance of itself from a base class (possibly via reflection?)

Tags: python, reflection, constructor

I have code that looks like the following and I'm trying to refactor it.

```
# Abstract, do not instantiate Base
class Base:
    ...


class A(Base):
    ...
    def func():
        x = A(1, 2, 3)
        x.x()
        y = A(4, 5, 6)
        y.y()
        z = A(7, 8, 9)
        z.z()

class B(Base):
    ...
    def func():
        x = B(1, 2, 3)
        x.x()
        y = B(4, 5, 6)
        y.y()
        z = B(7, 8, 9)
        z.z()


class C(Base):
    ...
    def func():
        x = C(1, 2, 3)
        x.x()
        y = C(4, 5, 6)
        y.y()
        z = C(7, 8, 9)
        z.z()
```

Due to the problem needing recursion to solve, the classes will recursively call themselves through `func()` (so A will make some A's that will make some more A's until the recursive function finishes), and the best way for me to refactor this is to dynamically create the class. If there was a way to get the final runtime class, I could refactor it to look like:

```
# Abstract, do not instantiate Base
class Base:
    ...
    def func():
        constructor = # Magic here to get the actual class type's constructor
        # I'm guessing reflection would do something like this...? I don't know.
        x = constructor.__init__(1, 2, 3) # If this is an A, make an A... if it's a B, make a B... etc
        x.x()
        y = constructor.__init__(4, 5, 6)
        y.y()
        z = constructor.__init__(7, 8, 9)
        z.z()

class A(Base):
    ...


class B(Base):
    ...


class C(Base):
    ...
```

I don't know much about Python and it's reflection capability, or if there's some other better way of doing this.

Can this be done?

Is there a better way than reflection?

*Note:* the constructor args are just arbitrary placeholders I made up.

*Note 2:* performance is irrelevant for this, I am just interested in if this is possible, and if so -- how?

---

Edit: Based on the answered solution, this code works:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Made BaseClass")
    def func(self):
        rofl = self.__class__()
        print(rofl.__class__)

class SubClass(Test):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("Made SubClass")

a = SubClass()
a.func()
```

Comment: Are you actually using `self` anywhere in these methods? If you have a method that needs to use the class, but not the instance, make it a `@classmethod`. That's what they're for. (Well, they're for simpler/more common versions of the same idea, like providing an alternate constructor… but effectively, you're doing the same thing an alternate constructor does for the same reason, so you can do the same thing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `__class__` attribute of the value:

```
class A(object):
     pass

class B(A):
     pass

b = B()
c = b.__class__()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you actually want here is to use class methods rather than regular methods.

You don't appear to be using `self` anywhere. In fact, you don't even really need an instance to *exist* for these functions to work. So:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Made BaseClass")
    @classmethod
    def func(cls):
        rofl = cls()
        print(rofl.__class__)

class SubClass(Test):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("Made SubClass")
```

Or, for your real case:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, *args): pass
    def x(self): pass
    def y(self): pass
    def z(self): pass
    @classmethod
    def func(cls):
        x = cls(1, 2, 3)
        x.x()
        y = cls(4, 5, 6)
        y.y()
        z = cls(7, 8, 9)
        z.z()

class A(Base): pass
class B(Base): pass
class C(Base): pass

a = A()
a.func() # calls Base.func, constructs and uses A instances

A.func() # also calls Base.func, constructs and uses A instances
```